# CSS box-shadow inconsistent

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have the following box-shadow:

```
box-shadow: -.4px .3px .1px .1px #009989;
```

Which renders as intended in Chrome like this:

[image]

But in Firefox like this:

[image]

And in Safari, it is not applied at all.
Browser prefixes are entirely ignored as they don't apply anymore (!important also doesn't work).
What is the common solution to get the desired result cross-browser?

Comment: Why use box-shadow when you can use border for your purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, box-shadow perfectly works on all browsers and you don't need vendor-specific prefixes. An only problem is that you should use more reasonable numbers in your code.

When you set, for example, spread to .1 pix (i.e. 1 / 10 pixel) the most of browsers correctly interpret that as "much less than a pixel is zero pixels" and so show nothing.

Just for testing purpose try

**box-shadow: -4px 3px 1px 1px #009989;**

and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening because of the decimal pixel values. For cross-browser compatibility, either use non-decimal pixel values or use `em` instead of `px`.

To use `em` you will need to set a base font-size. Let's say you set it to `10px`. Then the value of `0.4px` will be equal to `0.04em` and so on. Then you can do something like this:

```
box-shadow: -.04em .03em .01em .01em #009989;
```